# QML TextEdit.WordWrap mode breaks text without any whitespace into words

Tags: qml

I use a `TextEdit` component to display text, which can be multi-line depending on its width. The `wrapMode` is set to `TextEdit.WordWrap`, which means that wrapping is done on word boundaries only. So if there is only one word, the wrap should not work.

The problem is that for text that consists of one word, but starts with `\\`, this mode does not work and it wraps. Here is a simplified version of the problem code:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    id: root
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    TextEdit {
        anchors.fill: parent
        wrapMode: TextEdit.WordWrap
        font.pixelSize: 20
        text: "\\\\non_breaking_text_for_example"
    }
}
```

As a result, the text is wrapped between the first `\` character and the rest of the text:

[image]

If there are more `\` characters, the text will be wrapped after the penultimate `\`.

To prevent wrapping, I tried using `<p style="white-space: pre-wrap;"> + my_text + </p>` tag, but it had no effect. In addition, if I use `TextEdit.NoWrap` then the text really does not wrap.

So the question is why in this case `TextEdit.WordWrap` does not work and a single-word text wraps anyway? Can this be prevented?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: does this behaviour consists if you have another text not starting with \\n or \\r?

Comment: Perhaps I provided an unfortunate example that is misleading. It doesn't matter what character follows \\; it can be any letter, number, punctuation mark, etc. The wrap occurs specifically between the \ characters.

Comment: As a workaround, you could replace the \ for a similar-looking character, say `\``. As you're using it in a `TextEdit`, additional consideration is needed for both forward and backward conversions.